# Pass variable using class view in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

Directly how can I pass the context in the same time inside the class to my html pages?

the class is an updateView but I need the context in the page too:

```
class GL_PRUP(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Gas_liftM
    template_name = 'Home/WELLINFO/W_lift/GL_liftUPARMTS.html'
    form_class = Gas_liftFORM  
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def test_func(self):
        WeelN = self.get_object()
        GLParameters = Wcomlption.objects.filter(WellID__exact=WeelN)[0]
        print(GLParameters)
        context={'GLParameters': GLParameters,}  # need to pass this variable to my html page?
        if self.request.user== WeelN.author:
            return (True, context)
        else:
            return False
```

Every thing works fine in the update html page but only can't get the GLParameters??

```
{% if GLParameters %}
{{ GLParameters.WellID }} it works Tyaeb {{ GLParameters.Mndrn2 }}
{% else %}
nothing passes and happens 
{% endif %}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`UpdateView` inherits from multiple mixins and one of them is `SingleObjectMixin` that inherits from `ContextMixin` and thus you can override [get_context_data](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b5371539a9d871758d639a85d1f2fd648c1f633d/django/views/generic/detail.py#L91) method in order to extend the context with what you need.

Should be something like (untested):

```
...
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().context(**kwargs)
    WeelN = self.get_object()
    GLParameters = Wcomlption.objects.filter(WellID__exact=WeelN).first()
    context.update(
       {
           'GLParameters': GLParameters,
           'author': self.request.user == WeelN.author
       }
    )
    return context
```